# Html Selection C#

Tags: c#, html, select, html-agility-pack, xpath

I have multiple elements in the sourcecode which look like this.

```
<a  id="thread_title_158922" href="#"></a>
```

The problem is that i don't know the number behind title.
So i tried this syntax:

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(code);
        var items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@id='thread_title_*]");
```

But it's not working. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: "it's not working"? See http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code

Answer (score 2):

This works (tested):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(code);
var items = doc.DocumentNode
               .SelectNodes("//a[starts-with(@id,'thread_title_')]");
```

**Edit:**

I looked at the other answer before it was removed - and in my opinion that *should* have worked as well (or so I thought):

```
var items = doc.DocumentNode
               .SelectNodes("//a[@id='thread_title_*']"); //returs null
```

After some research it turns out that the XPath support in HtmAgilityPack for attributes does not support regular expressions but you can use functions such as `starts-with`, `contains`, `translate`, `substring-before` and `substring-after`. Just a gotcha to be aware of.